# java spring: assemble other independent services into a single service

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, transactions, spring-transactions

there are two services:

```
BookService {
    add(Book book);
    ...
}
```

and

```
MsgService {
    add(String msg);
    ...
}
```

the two services are independent. now i want this:

```
XService {
    @Transactional
    addBook(Book book) {
        BookService bs;
        MsgService ms;
        bs.add(book);
        ms.add("add a new book" + book);
    }
}
```

in this pattern, BookService and MsgService are like atom service, use Dao layer to do basic CRUD operations, and might be transactional, but not be exposed to client side; the one which will be is the XService, it calls several atom service to accomplish single transactional function(or saying complete business logic), like addBook().

here are my questions:

1, is this pattern OK?

2, if does, in which layer should the XService be? and what's the best name for X?

3, does the @Transactional in XService work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is fine, it is [commonly known as a Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). The `XService` class/logic should remain in the service/business layer. As to the name, that is up to you and depends on what the class is actually doing. Eg. if it is registering a book, call it RegistrationService.

As to the `@Transactional`, make sure your class is annotated with `@Service` or `@Component` and that it is in a package to be `component scanned` by Spring. If the services you wrap also have `@Transactional` methods, make sure the transactions either propagate or don't, again depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be exactly what I want, and I'll try it out.